Summary of numeric variable with missing values
Is there a R package that give me summary statistics of a numeric variable which include the percentage of missing values?
I have tried the built-in summary, Hmisc describe and psych describe, but non of those do:
> x <- rnorm(1000, 5, 0.6)
> x[sample(seq(1,length(x)),100)]<-NA
> summary(x)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max.       NA's 
3.12726377 4.62901915 5.02423569 5.02075611 5.39955795 7.52357325        100 
> Hmisc::describe(x)
x 
       n  missing distinct     Info     Mean  pMedian      Gmd      .05 
     900      100      900        1    5.021     5.02   0.6623    4.053 
     .10      .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
   4.267    4.629    5.024    5.400    5.809    6.000 

lowest : 3.12726 3.27157 3.37501 3.41268 3.41959
highest: 6.41032 6.44724 6.50692 6.54191 7.52357
> psych::describe(x)
   vars   n mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 900 5.02 0.59   5.02    5.02 0.57 3.13 7.52   4.4 0.01     0.17 0.02


I use the naniar package for summarising / exploring / plotting missing values - definitely worth checking out

Take a look at the skimr R package.
x <- rnorm(1000, 5, 0.6)
x[sample(seq(1,length(x)),100)] <- NA
skimr::skim(x)










Name
x


Number of rows
1000


Number of columns
1


_______________________



Column type frequency:



numeric
1


________________________



Group variables
None



Data summary
Variable type: numeric



skim_variable
n_missing
complete_rate
mean
sd
p0
p25
p50
p75
p100
hist




data
100
0.9
5
0.61
3.03
4.6
4.98
5.41
6.78
▁▃▇▅▁



Created on 2024-12-21 with reprex v2.0.2

In this case, the missing rate I asked in the question is 1-complete_rate
